# How to check if user have sucessfully logged in webrequest

Tags: c#, post, httpwebrequest

I have written a code and executes well I provide it username and password it implements POST but i dont know that login is sucessfull or not is there any way to check that?

```
var strId = UserName.Text;
var strName = UserPass.Text;
var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
var postData = "MainContent_LoginUser_UserName=" + strId + &MainContent_LoginUser_Password=" + strName + "&LoginButton";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:6226/WebSite1/Account/Login.aspx");

myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

var newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();

var response = myRequest.GetResponse();
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
textBox1.Text = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need HTTP response code. Usually 200 means success, 401 is Forbidden or 302 - redirect to login page.

EDIT: Actually, you are submitting to the login page, so 302 may indicate successful sign in and redirect to the default user page, it depends on what authentication type is enabled on the server and the logic behind login.aspx.

Comment: and what response code is returned when login with incorrect username/password for example in Yahoo mail ? relying to HTTP response code is a mistake. `200 OK` is necessary but not sufficient. Most of the time, even with incorrect login data you get `200 OK` but page contains details about login failure.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to look in the ResponseStream to see what information was returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you use cookie based authentication then server will respond with auth cookie when login success.

```
// Creating WebRequest  
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerPath + controllerName + "/" + actionName);  
var coockieContainer = new CookieContainer();

// AuthCookie is static variable defined. Initially it will be null. But when server  
// respond with auth cookie then we have to store it and add to container for further  
// communication.  

if (AuthCookie != null)  
{  
    coockieContainer.Add(AuthCookie);  
}  
req.CookieContainer = coockieContainer;  

req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"\"");  
req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";  
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;  
req.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript, */*";  
req.Method = "POST";  
var stm = req.GetRequestStream();  
stm.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);  
stm.Close();  
var resp = req.GetResponse();  

// If server respond with auth cookie then we have to store it.  
// Here I have used ".ASPXAUTH" name. You can have your own defined name
if (AuthCookie == null)  
{  
    AuthCookie = ((HttpWebResponse)resp).Cookies.Cast<Cookie>().Where(cook => 
cook.Name.Equals(".ASPXAUTH")).FirstOrDefault();  
    // Print the properties of each cookie.
    Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", AuthCookie.Name, AuthCookie.Value);  
    Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", AuthCookie.Domain);  
    Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", AuthCookie.Path);  
    Console.WriteLine("Port: {0}", AuthCookie.Port);  
    Console.WriteLine("Secure: {0}", AuthCookie.Secure);  
    Console.WriteLine("When issued: {0}", AuthCookie.TimeStamp);  
    Console.WriteLine("Expires: {0} (expired? {1})", AuthCookie.Expires, AuthCookie.Expired);  
    Console.WriteLine("Don't save: {0}", AuthCookie.Discard);  
    Console.WriteLine("Comment: {0}", AuthCookie.Comment);  
    Console.WriteLine("Uri for comments: {0}", AuthCookie.CommentUri);  
    Console.WriteLine("Version: RFC {0}", AuthCookie.Version == 1 ? "2109" : "2965");  

    // Show the string representation of the cookie.
    Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", AuthCookie.ToString());

}  

var stmr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());  

var json = stmr.ReadToEnd();
```